# Two java classes with different annotation values only

Tags: java, meta-programming, url-routing, servlets

Consider two classes:

*First*

```
@Path("/first/{param}") // 1st line
public class First {

    @GET
    @Path("/{data}/difference") // 5th line
    public Response doStuff(
            @Context HttpServletRequest request,
            @Context UriInfo uri,
            @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
            @PathParam("param") String param,
            @PathParam("data") String data
    ) {

        // whatever
        return new Response();

    }

}
```

*Second*

```
@Path("/second/{param}") // 1st line
public class Second extends First {

    @GET
    @Path("/{data}") // 5th line
    public Response doStuff(
            @Context HttpServletRequest request,
            @Context UriInfo uri,
            @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
            @PathParam("param") String param,
            @PathParam("data") String data
    ) {

        return super.doStuff(
            request,
            uri,
            httpHeaders,
            param,
            data
        );

    }

}
```

The only differences between this two block of code are:

- `@Path()` annotation value in the 1st line of both of them
- `@Path()` annotation value in the 5th line of both of them

How can I remove all the redundant code from it?

Comment: There is more different:  `return super.doStuff` and `extends` for example. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parameterize the @path annotation with regular expressions to specify one class/method that accepts multiple paths

```
@Path("/{firstpath: first|second}/{param}") // will match /first/{param} and /second/{param}
public class First {

    @GET
    @Path("/{data}{p:/?}{difference:(\w*)}") // {p:/?} makes "/" optional, {difference:(\w*)} allows for optional text
    public Response doStuff(
            @Context HttpServletRequest request,
            @Context UriInfo uri,
            @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
            @PathParam("param") String param,
            @PathParam("data") String data
    ) {

        // whatever
        return new Response();

    }

}
```